# Euro Truck Simulator 2 Multiplayer.com i cant register

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

i cant register it keep pooping up ads and im on asus and i cant x them out
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you cut off the bottom, I can't tell if you are seeing this or not:

[image: Sign in through STEAM]

If you can see that, click on the green button at the bottom. If not, go to this link in a new tab:

http://truckersmp.com/auth/register/associate

You should see a sign in page for Steam. Log into your account, and it should continue on with the registration.

Hope that helps!